# Log4j Logger.getLogger(Class) throws NPE when running with jMockit and Cobertura

Tags: java, maven, junit, cobertura, jmockit

I have found a strange interaction between cobertura-maven-plugin 2.6 and jmockit 1.8. A particular pattern in our production code has a class with a lot of static methods that effectively wraps a different class that acts like a singleton. Writing unit tests for these classes went fine until I tried to run coverage reports with cobertura, when this error cropped up:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.foo.MySingleton.<clinit>(MySingleton.java:7)
    ... 13 more
```

This then leads to a `NoClassDefFoundError` and being unable to initialize the singleton class. Here's a full SSCCE (the shortest I can get it down to) that replicates the error; line 7 of `MySingleton` is `Logger.getLogger()`.

Here's the "singleton"...

```
package com.example.foo;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MySingleton {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MySingleton.class);

    private boolean inited = false;
    private Double d;

    MySingleton() {
    }

    public boolean isInited() {
        return inited;
    }

    public void start() {
        inited = true;
    }

    public double getD() {
        return d;
        }
}
```

And the static class...

```
package com.example.foo;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyStatic {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyStatic.class);

    private static MySingleton u = new MySingleton();

    public static double getD() {
        if (u.isInited()) {
            return u.getD();
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

}
```

And the test that breaks everything...

```
package com.example.foo;

import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.Tested;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyStaticTest {

    @Tested MyStatic myStatic;

    @Mocked MySingleton single;

    @Test
    public void testThatBombs() {
        new Expectations() {{
            single.isInited(); result = true;
            single.getD(); /*result = 1.2;*/
        }};

//        Deencapsulation.invoke(MyStatic.class, "getD");
        MyStatic.getD();

    }

}
```

And the maven pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

To summarize the summary: When running an ordinary unit test (`mvn clean test`), the above tests just fine; when run with cobertura (`mvn clean cobertura:cobertura`) it throws the nasty set of exceptions shown at the top. Obviously a bug somewhere, but whose?

Comment: One detail: the pom.xml file must *not* put the plugin inside a `pluginManagement` section, as it won't take effect.

Comment: It won't take effect when I run `mvn cobertura:cobertura` and explicitly invoke the plugin? Interesting... ok, I'll try it directly inside `<plugins/>` and see if that helps any.

Comment: That made no difference, sorry to say.

Comment: I know, but it would be good to edit the question to fix the pom. As for the origin of the NPE, I am going to write an answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause for this problem isn't so much a bug, but a lack of robustness in JMockit when mocking a class that contains a static initializer. The next version of JMockit (1.9) will be improved on this point (I already have a working solution).

Also, the problem would not have occurred if Cobertura marked its generated methods (four of them with names starting with "__cobertura_", added to every instrumented class) as "synthetic", so that JMockit would have ignored them when mocking a Cobertura-instrumented class. Anyway, fortunately this won't be necessary.

For now, there are two easy work-arounds which avoid the problem:

1. Make sure any class to be mocked was already initialized by the JVM by the time the test starts. This can be done by instantiating it or invoking a static method on it.
2. Declare the mock field or mock parameter as `@Mocked(stubOutClassInitialization = true)`.

Both work-arounds prevent the NPE that would otherwise get thrown from inside the static class initializer, which is modified by Cobertura (to see these bytecode modifications, you can use the `javap` tool of the JDK, on classes under the `target/generated-classes` directory).

Comment: I was never able to get the workarounds to work for me, but JMockit 1.9 solves the problem, so thank you very much!