# Error in Parameterised test cases in Junit

Tags: junit, parameter-passing, powermock, spy

I am trying to write a parameterized test case in JUnit. My code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@PrepareForTest({AR9DirectDebitFileWriterCustomization.class})
public class AR9DirectDebitFileWriterCustomizationTest2 extends AR3BasicUnitTest {

     private DirectDebitExtractDetRec mockObj;
     private  ARApplicationContext mockAppCon;
     private AR9DirectDebitFileWriterCustomization spyObj = null;
    AccountDBViewData mockdbData;


    AccountDBView mockdbView;

    SearchInvoicesDBViewData[]   mocksearchInvdbviewdatarr   = new SearchInvoicesDBViewData[1];

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

        AR9DirectDebitFileWriterCustomization ar9Obj = new AR9DirectDebitFileWriterCustomization(mockdbView, mocksearchInvdbviewdatarr, mockdbData);
        spyObj = PowerMockito.spy(ar9Obj);

    }

public AR9DirectDebitFileWriterCustomizationTest2(DirectDebitExtractDetRec mockObj_from_collection, ARApplicationContext mockAppCon_from_collection) {
              this.mockObj = mockObj_from_collection;
              this.mockAppCon = mockAppCon_from_collection;
           }

@Parameterized.Parameters   
    public static Collection<Object[]> getparameters() throws ACMException{
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {mock(DirectDebitExtractDetRec.class),mock(ARApplicationContext.class)}
        });
    }

@Test
@Parameters
public final  void testAddFileRecordCustObjectARApplicationContext( ) throws Exception {
.....SOME CODE 
}
```

Whenever I right click on the testAddFileRecordCustObjectARApplicationContext function and run it as Junit test I get an initialization  error :

> java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method
>   testAddFileRecordCustObjectARApplicationContext(amdocs.ar.customizationexits.handlers.helpers.AR9DirectDebitFileWriterCustomizationTest2)
>   from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@3fa50b  at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestMethodReference.(JUnit4TestMethodReference.java:25)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:54)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

After looking for several hours on internet about this issue I could not find anything meaningful. In this scenario I am using spy and powerMocktio Functionality as well.I am not sure what is the root of this error .
And interesting thing is when I run it without using Parameterised test ,it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is there also an "unrooted tests" error shown? Also, what version of JUnit and your IDE? If you are using Eclipse, this question is likely to be related: [JUnit parameterized tests: how do I run only 1 specific test from IntelliJ/Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16517300)

Comment: yes there is unrooted error shown. I am using junit 4.1 and I am using a customized version of Eclipse IDE in a company.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar error:

```
No tests found matching data with any parameter from...
```

According to my observations, it is caused by another strange error:

```
Unable to mock class ... due to a missing dependency
```

Only the first I see when I run the test, and the second, when I debug it. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23788935/715269, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25659518/715269, it is the bug connected to classpath reading. The problem disappears, when we upgrade JMockit to higher versions.